# Error when passing text values as parameters to Crystal Report Formula field from VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to pass some text to a formula field in a Crystal Report.

Formula field name is `txtShopName`.

`shopName` is a variable and it has the value of "TORCH-MINIMALL". I use VB.net to view the report and pass the parameter value as follows. However, I get an error when trying to view the report. (Image attached)

What could be the reason?. Is there any specific way which I have to create the formula field in the report?.

```
Dim crepBill As New repBill
crepBill.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", dbPwd)
crepBill.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("txtShopName").Text = shopName
crepBill.RecordSelectionFormula = "{TB_SALES.bill_no} ='" & "B000002" & "'"
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crepBill
CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(100)
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following line sets the formula to `TORCH-MINIMALL` while it should be `"TORCH-MINIMALL"`

```
crepBill.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("txtShopName").Text = shopName
```

To add the double quotes, change the code as follows:

```
crepBill.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("txtShopName").Text = """" & shopName & """"
```

Or you could also use single qoutes, as Crystal Reports support both:

```
crepBill.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("txtShopName").Text = "'" & shopName & "'"
```

---

If showing a text is the only purpose of the formula-field, then one can also use a parameter-field.

The value of a parameter-field can be set as follows:

```
crepBill.SetParameterValue("nameOfTheParameterField", shopName)
```

Comment: It's a great answer. I was looking all over the internet for this. thank you.